# Can not able to access record type array column using dataflow for key value conversion

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create key and values for `existingTableData` and `NewSourceData` from Dataflow pipeline. I have to update all the details inside the merchant_array column of `existingTableRow` on the basis of `NewSourceData`. After that I need to perform `coGroupBykey` on it.

existingTableData-

```
{Config_sk=sk1 ,level2_value=group,max_number=5,
merchant_array=[{name=Allen, merchant_number=00101,phone_number=9876543210,country=india,address=FC Road},{name=kevin, merchant_number=00102,phone_number=9876553210,country=USA,address= link Road}]}
```

NewSourceData-

```
{Config_sk=sk1 ,level2_value=group,max_number=5,
merchant_array=[{name=Allen K, merchant_number=00101,phone_number=9885522456,country=india,address=FC Road, India},{name=kevin, merchant_number=00102,phone_number=9876553210,country=USA,address= link Road}]}
```

I need to create key on `"merchant_number"` column which is basically inside an array(record type). here I need to create key-value for every table row inside the `merchant_array`.

I have tried this but getting `ClassCastException`. or if I am directly getting the key from tablerow it throwing `NullPointerException`.

DoFn class -

```
public class KVCreation extends DoFn<TableRow, KV<String,List<TableRow>>> 
{
  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KVCreation.class);
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) 
  {
    TableRow existingData=c.element();
    LOG.info("existingData",existingData);
    System.out.println(existingData);
    String  id =null;
      
    List<TableRow>  tableData=  (List<TableRow>) existingData.get("merchant_array");
     for( TableRow tbl:tableData)
     {    
      System.out.println("tbl"+tbl); 
      id =  tbl.get("merchant_number").toString();
      
     }  
    
    System.out.println("KV"+KV.of(id,tableData));
     c.output(KV.of(id,tableData));
     
  }
}
```

Please suggest how can I achive this using dataflow.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084143/classcastexception-when-reading-nested-list-of-records-dataflow-bigquery

Comment: @Pablo That part I am already using. My main concern here is how can I make the kv of that type of data and perform further operations.

Comment: ah so the error occurs when you call c.output on the KV?

Comment: yes correct. Pablo I have post one more question,can you please answer this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62625774/9558906